# call JAX-RS using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jax-rs

I'm using JAX-RS to build Restufl web application , I have a problem from calling a webservice with post method that consumes a json object.
I must call the webservice using jquery
this is the method

```
 @POST
@Path("/client")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Response showClient(Client c){
     String name = c.getAdresseCl() + ""+ c.getEmailCl();
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(name);
    builder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    builder.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    builder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
    builder.header(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "X-Requested-With,Host,User-Agent,Accept,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Charset,Keep-Alive,Connection,Referer,Origin");
    return builder.build();
}
```

client call with jquery :

```
  var data={'adressCl':'myAdress','emailCl':'example@domain.com'};
$.ajax({
"type":"post",
"dataType":"json",
"data":data,
"url":"http://localhost:9080/FournisseurWeb/jaxrs/clients/client",
"success":function(res){
console.log(res);
}
});/*
$.post("http://localhost:9080/FournisseurWeb/jaxrs/clients/client",data,function(res){
console.log(res);
});*/
```

I get this error : "NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type
please help! and thx in advance

Comment: Moderators this is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679060/ajax-call-to-jax-rs-with-jquery-issue. Please delete.

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ `contentType` field description it looks like .ajax() is sending by default application/x-www-form-urlencoded, not json, so you need to set that properly: application/json

I've never checked that, but I always use "type":"POST" not "type":"post", maybe that's the problem.